# SharePoint Provider Hosted Low Trust App Error: 'An error occurred while processing your request.'

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have an OnPremise SharePoint 2013 and a O365 tenant. I have setup/configured a SharePoint Provider Hosted Low Trust Development Environment based on the step by step guide provided by the Microsfot Patterns and Practices Team:

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/blob/master/Scripts/SharePoint.LowTrustACS.Configuration

I have also built a simple Low Trust App which has absolutely no functionality!

1. I have a created a new Client and Secret
2. provided the domain -> dyn-app.mydomain.com
3. provided the redirect url -> https://dyn-app.mydomain.com/splowtrust1
4. Go to Visual Studio Low Trust Solution and added the client id and scret to the web.config
5. I published the app locally on my app website in IIS (with ssl configured)
6. i packaged the app with the url: https://dyn-app.mydomain.com/splowtrust1 and generated client id
7. uploaded the app to the app catalog
8. created a new app

When i click on the app i am getting redirected to my local iis correctly but i am receiving:

> An error occurred while processing your request.

What is causing this error? And how can i fix it?

Comment: Try giving permissions to the app. Go to the AppManifest of the app and give Contribute access to SiteCollection and Web and try deploying the app again. Please let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Jyotsna, i gave permission to my user (Administrator) dedicated permissions on site level (Owner) and in App Manifest "Full Control" for Web. Retracted solution and deployed again, but no change! Still same error as in question.